# Wordpress can't edit some pages anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress website has a strange problem: **some** pages cannot be updated anymore. It happens not with all pages, a few pages are working without problems.

After saving my edits, Wordpress shows me the message 'Your page is updated successfully' (or some other English translation) but it is not! My edit is gone and there is no extra revision.

What I tried so far:

- Disabled all the plugins;
- Disabled SSL;
- Checked if server / plugin caching was enabled (it was not);
- Disabled the browser cache;
- Checked the .htaccess file (it's the default Wordpress .htaccess);
- Rebuild the entire website (empty FTP and empty database);
- Checked my (custom build) template for vulnerabilities;
- Enabled the default twenty-seventeen theme;
- Repaired the database (in DirectAdmin);
- Contacted the webhoster (but they didn't understand the problem);
- Moved the website to another domain;
- Compared working pages with not working pages (but no difference);
- Logged in with different users;

The error / debug log is empty and WP_DEBUG (and some PHP debug stuff) is enabled.

Suggestions are welcome ;)

### Solution

I finally found the problem! Wordpress creates a GUID for each post. You can see the GUID in your database, or export your pages using the Wordpress export module.

For some strange reason, the content of the GUID is some text from the page itself. So, it looks like this:

> strongWinterwerk%202016-2017/strongU/jij%20bent%20van%20harte%20welkom%20om%20één%20of%20meerdere%20activiteiten%20die%20in%20onze%20gemeente%20worden%20gehouden%20in%20de%20komende%20maanden%20te%20volgen.%20Hierbij%20ontvangt%20u%20de%20seizoenplanning%20en%20meer%20informatie%20over%20clubs%20en%20verenigingen%20

This GUID contains 317 characters. But, the database column can only store 255 characters. I changed it to 500 characters and my website works. Of course isn't this a good solution, but fine for now.

Just a few more questions:

- Why is my GUID not just something like `http://website.com/welcom-page`?
- If there is only room for 255 characters, why are there 317 stored while creating the post?

Comment: Did this just start on it's own, or did you update something? Have you checked the server's error logs for information?

Comment: Yes, it just started on it's own. About five months ago. I had updated Wordpress multiple times, but it didn't work.

Comment: When you rebuilt the site, did you download a fresh copy of WP and delete the old one from the server (keeping wp-contents)? FYI you may also want to post this over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I had downloaded a brand new Wordpress version and walked through the installation wizard. Then I uploaded my theme to the wp-content folder.

Comment: is there any error log in your server. Please check it. Also make WP_DEBUG to true. So that you can check the wordpress errors.

Comment: @NewUser, WP_DEBUG is true and the error log is clean.

Comment: Did you tried updating wordpress

Comment: @Marten Did you tried updating wordpress version. If yes. Remove all the content from the page and just put some dummy text and check it by updating the the page which is having issue.

Comment: @J.Shabu Wordpress is up-to-date. What you suggest doesn't work. I cannot remove the content and replace it by some dummy text.

Comment: Where do your texts for title and content come from? I mean, do you enter them manually or do you copy them from another document? Maybe you copied some junk-code from MS Word or so?